# In a leex grammar file definition, is there a Regex rule for matching exactly N elements?

Tags: erlang, elixir, leex

Looking thru the [documentation for leex](http://erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html), I don't see an example of matching exactly N elements, like `(element){n}`?

This fails:

```
Definitions.

ThreeFoos = foo{3}
```

The work around is this:

```
Definitions.

ThreeFoos = foofoofoo
```

So if I had a case where I want to match 3,000 foo's, the definition `ThreeThousandFoos = foofoofoo<2,997 more foos>` would get pretty unwieldy.  There are hacks, like constructing increasingly large foo definitions from smaller ones (e.g. `SixteenFoos = {EightFoos}{EightFoos}`), but that seems silly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the support in `leex` for interval ranges was [commented out six years ago](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/3b4137c64d9259c9f5ac59b89ff44f340256ee7a#diff-22d5e38b5770310b1e2839524c4c8944R666) in Erlang/OTP and [never included back again](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blame/master/lib/parsetools/src/leex.erl#L693).